# Neo4j compare sums from different queries and display result

Tags: neo4j, nosql, neo4j-apoc

Is there a way that i compare results from different queries? Could the following queries be written in a single query together with the return for the **wanted result**?

***Query1***: Returns countries and SUM from all points given by countries that are not part of their region.

```
MATCH (c:Country)
with c
MATCH (c)-[vFrom:vote_from]->(vP:vote_points)-[vFor:vote_for]->(c2:Country)
with c,c2,vP
where not c.region=c2.region
return c2.name,sum(toInteger(vP.points))
```

*Example return from Query1:*

```
"Monaco"    11
"Montenegro"    34
"France"    359
"Cyprus"    600
"Romania"   837
```

***Query2***: Returns countries and SUM from all points given by countries that are part of their region.

```
MATCH (c:Country)
with c
MATCH (c)-[vFrom:vote_from]->(vP:vote_points)-[vFor:vote_for]->(c2:Country)
with c,c2,vP
where  c.region=c2.region
return c2.name,c.name,sum(toInteger(vP.points))
```

*Example return from Query2:*

```
"Monaco"    35
"Montenegro"    66
"France"    157
"Cyprus"    102
"Romania"   255
```

***Wanted result:***

```
"Monaco"    35
"Montenegro"    66
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your wanted result. Can you explain it ?

Comment: @logisima It compares the results from Query 2 with Query 1 and only displays the ones from query 2 that have more points then Query1. Example Monaco in Query 1 has 11 points and in Query 2 it has 35 points so it displays it in the wanted result, however France in Query 1 has 359 points which is greater then the points in Query 2 ( France 157) points  and because of that this doesnt belong in the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for cases where in-region point totals exceed out-of-region totals, this query may work for you:

```
MATCH (c:Country)-[:vote_from]->(vP:vote_points)-[:vote_for]->(c2:Country)
WITH c2,
  REDUCE(s={in: 0, out: 0}, x IN COLLECT({reg: c.region, pts: toInteger(vP.points)}) |
    CASE WHEN x.reg=c2.region
      THEN {in: s.in + x.pts, out: s.out}
      ELSE {in: s.in, out: s.out + x.pts}
    END) AS res
WHERE res.in > res.out
RETURN c2.name AS name, res.in AS points
```

Comment: That's exactly what i needed! Thanks a lot!